# Returning DbQuery to view that requires IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

**The problem:**

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item
>   passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Int32]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'migros.Models.State'.

**What I'm trying to do**

I need to pass the result of the following linq query to a View.

```
using (var db = new migros_mockEntities1())
        {
            var listOfIdeas = (from x in db.States select x.ID); 

            return View(listOfIdeas);
        }
```

The View requires `IEnumerable`, but it seems I can't cast the result of the linq query to `IEnumerable`. 
I'm using entity framework database first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to return ObjectQuery  from within the using block.
Try to materialize your object-set

```
var listOfIdeas = (from x in db.States select x.ID).ToList();
```

Also, dont forget, that dealing with context can be tricky. 
In your case `var listOfIdeas = (from x in db.States select x.ID)` is just a query, that will run only when you'd begin to iterate over it. So, if context gets already disposed you'd get an exception, trying to use `listOfIdeas`.

Comment: I get an exception, one that says I'm trying to pass an object of type System.Collections.Generic.List and it requires one of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: Eureka! That was it, the view was expecting an object of a type defined by me and, dumb me, I was sending an int to it. Thx for the help.