# Linq to View error, Passing Generic List : Required IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, viewmodel

Visual Studio 2012 Internet Aplication MVC4 C#

**ERROR**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

My View Expects: `@model IEnumerable<OG.Models.UserProfiles>` this is a *data*Model not ViewModel. *This View is also one generate by the `UserProfiles` Model when I created the Controller ( Standart Scaffolding with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)` and later the `@foreach (var item in Model) {` to list data`

My Controller Attempts:

- Attempt 1 *Aware ( not returning list )*

  ```
  return View(db.UserProfiles
               .Include(c => c.Roles)
               .Where(c => c.Roles.Any(up => up.RoleName != "Administrator"))
               .Select(c => new
               {
                   UserID = c.UserID,
                   UserName = c.UserName,
                   UserCount = c.Roles.Count()
               }));
  ```
- Attempt 2 *Aware ( not returning list )*

  ```
          var model =
              from usr in db.UserProfiles
              join rls in db.UserRoles on usr.Roles equals rls.RoleId

              select new { UserID = usr.UserID, UserName = usr.UserName };
  ```
- Attempt 3 *Aware ( not returning list )*

  ```
          var model =
             from usr in db.UserProfiles.Include(t => t.Roles)
             where usr.Roles.Any(up => up.RoleName != "Administrator")
             select new WebAdminUsersLookup
             {
                 UserID = usr.UserID,
                 UserName = usr.UserName
             };
  ```
- Attempt 4 *Guess this isn't a "real" list, still errors*

  ```
  var listOfIdeas = 
       (from x in db.UserProfiles.Include(t => t.Roles)
       .Where(u => u.Roles.Any(up => up.RoleName != "Administrator"))
       select new { UserID = x.UserID, UserName = x.UserName }).ToList();
  ```
- For attempts 1-3

  ```
          List<UserProfiles> modelList = new List<UserProfiles>();
          modelList.Add(model.ToList());
  ```

something like that and *Created a Viewmodel for them*

```
    private class WebAdminUsersLookup
    {
        //public List<UserProfiles> Users { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set;}
    }
```

Websites Searched:

- [This Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813307/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-req)
- [And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879870/returning-dbquery-to-view-that-requires-ienumerable)
- [and this one](http://forums.asp.net/t/1280704.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your view expects `IEnumerable<OG.Models.UserProfiles>` then this is what you should pass to it, not some anonymous objects that you are projecting in your LINQ queries. If `IEnumerable<OG.Models.UserProfiles>` is not enough for your view and you need additional information then you'd better create a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int RolesCount { get; set; }
}
```

and then project on this view model:

```
IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model = db
    .UserProfiles
    .Include(c => c.Roles)
    .Where(c => c.Roles.Any(up => up.RoleName != "Administrator"))
    .Select(c => new MyViewModel
    {
        UserID = c.UserID,
        UserName = c.UserName,
        RolesCount = c.Roles.Count()
     });

return View(model);
```

and finally make your view strongly typed to the same model as what you are passing in your controller action:

```
@model IEnuemrable<MyViewModel>
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate that, Im still getting used to Types in MVC, this worked for me, just need to work on my Linq query, aparently it doesn't show anyone , reguardless of Admin role or not, but thats neither here nor there. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

Convert your model to List and pass it to your View like below:

```
 var model = db.UserProfiles
 .Include(c => c.Roles)
 .Where(c => c.Roles.Any(up => up.RoleName != "Administrator")).ToList();

 return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, but im also using this for the (Standart view() that requires IEnumerable) :) - sry to not have specified. +1 good answer